# SUM by row, not the entire query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

With the following query:

```
SELECT
    ACT_CODE,
    ORL_EVENT,
    ACT_NOTE,
    (SUM(ORL_PRICE*ORL_ORDQTY)) AS 'ORD_TOTAL'
FROM
    R5ORDERLINES 
INNER JOIN
    R5ACTIVITIES on ACT_EVENT = ORL_EVENT
WHERE
    ORL_EVENT = '123'
GROUP BY 
    ACT_CODE, ORL_EVENT, ACT_NOTE
ORDER BY 
    ACT_ACT
```

I get a result like this, where the ORD_TOTAL is the SUM of all rows, when I need the total for each ACT_CODE (total for all Houses, all Cars, etc) not for all products.

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|ACT_CODE|ORL_EVENT| ACT_NOTE  | ORD_TOTAL|
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|1110    |123      | Houses    | 2500     |
|1111    |123      | Cars      | 2500     |
|1112    |123      | TVs       | 2500     |
|1113    |123      | Computers | 2500     |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Actually I need it to be like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|ACT_CODE|ORL_EVENT| ACT_NOTE  | ORD_TOTAL|
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|1110    |123      | Houses    | 1250     |
|1111    |123      | Cars      |  500     |
|1112    |123      | TVs       |  250     |
|1113    |123      | Computers |  500     |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

I tried to lots of query modifications but nothing seems to work... and I am not expert on this.

Comment: Doesn't this give an error. You don't have act_code in group by.

Comment: And to get a reply, please give sample data. In its current form, all I see a query that should be throwing an error.

Comment: My mistake, ACT_ORDER should be ACT_CODE in group by, It was just a mistake when adapting it before posting. Post edited.

Comment: OK can you also give some sample data.

Comment: @Piston Post the tables and their data. The only way to get identical sums is to have identical data in the table. Most likely a bad join condition returned the same order lines for all activities.

Comment: You are joining by `ACT_EVENT = ORL_EVENT` and `ORL_EVENT` is the same in all rows. You are only summing fields from the Order Lines table so it's only logical that you'd get the same value - it's the same event after all

Comment: You don't have anything to group the results bu act_code. Same ACT_EVENT exists in all ACT_CODEs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I just had to change the inner join relation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `PARTITION BY` Clause. I have modified the query like below. Not tested as I do not have data. Please check and revert.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACT_CODE,
    ORL_EVENT,
    ACT_NOTE,
    (SUM(ORL_PRICE*ORL_ORDQTY) OVER(PARTITION BY ACT_NOTE) AS 'ORD_TOTAL'
FROM
    R5ORDERLINES 
INNER JOIN
    R5ACTIVITIES on ACT_EVENT = ORL_EVENT
WHERE
    ORL_EVENT = '123'
ORDER BY 
    ACT_ACT
```